# Coded UI not able to find element in msocaf 2010. However working fine for msocaf 2013

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We are trying to automate msocaf analysis using coded UI.

Once the analysis is run we get the results if the folder structure is passed or not and other details displayed in a cell.

Using coded UI we are able to able to fetch the element successfully in msocaf 2013. However in 2010 we get element not found exception.

Can anyone please help out to resolve the same

Comment: Check the release notes of the two versions for their compatibility with Coded UI, or ask the suppliers.

Comment: Is there any way out to fetch the value in the cell for Status column which has the value as Folder Structure-Passed, Extraction - Passed, Finding references - Failed, Analysis - Failed. for msocaf 2010 tool using Coded UI

Comment: ... and what do the release notes say about Coded UI support?

Comment: Release notes does not mention anything. But verified in two 2010 and 2013 environments to confirm that it is not working in 2010 environments and working in 2013 environments

Comment: Coded UI needs to be supported by the application being tested, otherwise Coded UI will not be able to interact with the application. You need to find out from the suppliers whether the 2010 version includes Coded UI support. All you have shown so far it that it works for 2013 version and not for the 2010 version. My comments so far are trying to get you to investigate whether the suppliers of the program expect it to work with Coded UI. Many programs do not support Coded UI as it can be difficult to do, but it is a good upgrade for newer versions.